# Segmenting data frame by row based on specific pattern

Tags: r

Sorry for not precisely titling the problem. Let me elaborate as follows:

I have data frame like this:

```
   state
1      v
2      v
3      v
4      v
5      x
6      x
7      x
8      v
9      v
10     x
11     x
12     v
13     v
14     x
```

I want to segment it into three parts:

First part:

```
   state
1      v
2      v
3      v
4      v
5      x
6      x
7      x
```

second part:

```
8      v
9      v
10     x
11     x
```

third part:

```
12     v
13     v
14     x
```

That is, each part will contain at least two "state" ("v" and "x") regardless of the number and part with pattern "v,v,x,x,v" (x followed with v) should not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique identifier with `cumsum` and use `split` to split the data frame.

```
split(dat, c(0, cumsum(with(dat, state[-1] == "v" & head(state, -1) == "x"))))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

The result is a list including three data frames.

```
$`0`
  state
1     v
2     v
3     v
4     v
5     x
6     x
7     x

$`1`
   state
8      v
9      v
10     x
11     x

$`2`
   state
12     v
13     v
14     x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> n=0
> ddf$new = n
> for(i in 2:nrow(ddf)){
+ if(ddf$state[i] =='v' &&  ddf$state[i-1] =='x') {n=n+1}
+ ddf$new[i] = n
+ }
> split(ddf, ddf$new)
$`0`
   sno state new
1:   1     v   0
2:   2     v   0
3:   3     v   0
4:   4     v   0
5:   5     x   0
6:   6     x   0
7:   7     x   0

$`1`
   sno state new
1:   8     v   1
2:   9     v   1
3:  10     x   1
4:  11     x   1

$`2`
   sno state new
1:  12     v   2
2:  13     v   2
3:  14     x   2
```